# Shell Script Comparar valores multilinha de variável com string

Tags: linux, shell-script

Fala pessoal!
Como faço para comparar uma variável multilinha (2 linhas) com uma string sendo que tem que validar uma linha por vez o conteúdo da variável é:

ambiente_1
ambiente_2

código te teste:

```
#!/bin/bash

#valor da variável vem de 1 arquivo que contém as duas linhas
ambientes=$(<ambiente)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
if [ ${ambientes} == "ambiente" ]; then                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
echo "$ambientes"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
else
       echo "O valor é: $ambientes"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
fi
```

Sempre da erro na validação pois ele tenta comparar com os 2 valores ao mesmo tempo, eu preciso que o script compare primeiro com 1 valor e depois o outro entendo que vou precisar fazer algum laço de repetição mas ainda não sei como fazer para comparar o valor de cada linha separadamente. É possível?

Answer (score 0):

Precisará um laço para ler as variáveis e compará-las

```
#!/bin/bash
#valor da variável vem de 1 arquivo que contém as duas linhas
    
#le o arquivo ambiente    
IFS=$' ' read -d '' -r -a LINES < ambiente
# laço processa cada variavel    
for i in "${LINES[@]}"; do
      if [ $i == "ambiente" ]; then                                                                                                                            
           echo "$i"                                                                                                                                        
      else
           echo "O valor é: $i"                                                                                                                              
      fi
done
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!
Só que mesmo com esse script ele continua comparando os 2 valores ao mesmo tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução e na verdade era bem simples.
O próprio for já faz essa iteração.

```
#!/bin/bash
#valor da variável vem de 1 arquivo que contém as duas linhas
    
ambientes=$(<ambiente)

for i in $ambientes
  do      
      if [ "$i" == "ambiente_1" ]; then                                                                                                                            
            echo "O valor é igual: $i"                                                                                                                                        
      else
            echo "O valor é diferente: $i"                                                                                                                                         
      fi
  done
```